# How do I access my query when using Haystack/Elasticsearch?

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I originally followed this tutorial (https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html), and have so far been able to highlight my query within my returned results. However, I want to highlight this same query when visiting the next page that I load with a separate template. Is there any way to save/access this query so that I can highlight the same results within this other template?

Whenever I try and include a statement like this, I get an error, which I'm thinking is because I'm not trying to access the query properly.

```
{% highlight section.body with query html_tag "span" css_class "highlighted" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to send to the next page, the information that you use to highlight the results in the first page. You can use the request.session to store the data and call it in the next page, or you can send the sqs by the url to the next page.

If you want to know how to manage the search query set, and how to edit that kind of stuff, I recommend you to read the views.py forms.py and the elasticsearch_backend in the haystack folder at: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/haystack"

This is the url for the documentation of Django Session: [Django Session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/)

This is the url for the documentation to pass parameters trhough url:  [URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/)